# How to monitor an asynchronous thread started via GcmListenerService

Tags: android, multithreading, asynchronous, callback, google-cloud-messaging

I'm wondering if someone can give me a brief overview of how to have my main activity communicate with an asynchronous thread started via GcmListenerService.  This is what I'm doing...

- GcmListenerService listens for GCM message
- When message is picked up an asynchronous REST request is made that ultimately downloads a file
- ***missing part:*** When the file is downloaded the main activity needs to know so it can deal with the new file

Should I...?

- Create a static reference to my GcmListenerService in my main activity and start it there (at the moment its started via the AndroidManifest)
- create a callback in my REST download class and have the GcmListenerService implement it
- create a callback in my GcmListenerService and implement it in my main activity

This just doesn't seen right.  There must be a better way?

Comment: 3d one seems fine for me. Some popular libs like https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader force you to implement callback for downloadFinished event.

Comment: should have been a little clearer.  The way I see it is that I would need to do all 3 of those points in order to achieve the desired result.  I would need the download request result to cascade down.  REST Class-> GcmListenerService -> Main Activity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use EventBus, it simplifies the communication that you need.
https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus

Comment: Thanks Alexey!  Now I feel like I'm cheating.  Surly that's too simple!  the lib worked a treat.